# Apply equation to a single int

Tags: python, equation

In short, I have a list of ISBN numbers and have to return the list of invalid numbers, but I'm having trouble taking a int from the list, for example `9781523844011`, and applying it the equation to check if the ISBN is valid:

```
9 + 7x3 + 8 + 1x3 + 5 + 2x3 + 3 + 8x3 + 4 + 4x3 + 0 + 1x3 + 1
```

I've tried the following:

```
nf=[]     #nf is the list I want to return and n is the list I'am drawing the ISBN numbers from
for j in range(0, len(n)):
    if len(str(n[j]))!=13:
        nf.append(n[j])
    else:
        val = (sum(int(x) for x in n[::2]) + sum(int(x) * 3 for x in n[1::2]))  #this is the equation code I came up with
        if val%10!=0:
            nf.append(n[j])
        j+=1
```

So I should be getting the list of invalid ISBN's:

```
[9789720046711, 9789896604011]
```

But I am getting the entirity of the ISBN number (the n) list:

```
[9789722036757, 9789720046711, 9789720047572, 9789896604011]
```

Comment: Your formula isn't doing anything with `n[j]`.

Comment: Things get much easier if you use `for isbn in n` rather than using the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing your equation on all the ISBN numbers in `n`, not the digits of the current ISBN number. `n` is the entire list, so `n[::2]` and `n[1::2]` are slices of all the numbers.

You need to convert the current number into a list of digits, then process that.

```
for isbn in n:
    if len(str(isbn))!=13:
        nf.append(isbn)
    else:
        digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(isbn).split("")]
        val = sum(digits[::2]) + sum(x * 3 for x in digits[1::2])
        if val % 10 != 0:
            nf.append(isbn)
```